# Can someone please tell me why I cannot clear these fields?

Tags: payment

Don't know what this info is and when I delete it and go to save configuration it just reappears. No online orders are being processed.  Keep getting message 'Gateway Error: credit card number is required'  Could this be the cause?

[image: Payment Services Tab]

Comment: What is your current payment method? As the fields are yellow i think they are just saved by your browser.

Answer (score 3):

The fields in yellow are being auto-filled by your browser's saved password functionality.  You can find directions on removing the saved password here: http://www.bu.edu/tech/services/support/desktop/software/troubleshooting/removing-password-from-browsers-saved-password-list/